# Statistical test to find the determinants of being in a particular group?

Tags: regression, logistic, group-differences

I have data on a population of people who have had a formal workplace issue e.g. poor performance, bullying, poor attendance etc. I want to find out if their characteristics increase the likelihood of being in this population e.g. their gender, ethnicity, disability etc. I'm wondering what technique to use.

My instinct is to do a logistic regression, which I think means that I need to obtain the characteristics of the rest of the workforce who do NOT have a formal issue. But I'm wondering if there are any alternative methods which could be used - perhaps ones which didn't involve collecting data on the 'other' group which do not have a workplace issue.

A second step in my analysis may be to investigate the drivers of particular types of workplace issue since some are more serious than others - poor attendance or gross misconduct. And perhaps the outcome - which could range from no formal action to dismissal. Perhaps multinomial regression would be best for that.

Comment: Can you give us some more details, like sample size? and, you say *I have data on a population of people* does that mean you have data on your complete population of interest?

Comment: Thanks for your response. There are around 2000 people in the workforce and around 200 in the poor performance group. I currently have data on the characteristics of the 200. I could fairly easily get it for the other 1,800 - which i will do if i decide to do a logistic regression.

Comment: Can you please include this new information as an edit to the post? Not everybody reads comments!  And, at least as a start, go for logistic regression.